# Permission denied for relation <table>

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have ran the following SQL in psql:

```
CREATE USER bspu LOGIN;

CREATE DATABASE bsp OWNER bspu;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE bsp TO bspu;

\c bsp

CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  api_key VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  api_secret VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  auth_token VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);
```

When I login as `bspu`, and try to query the `users` table, I get the error:

> ```
> permission denied for relation users
> ```

I tried running:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO bspu;
```

But it doesn't help. What am I doing wrong? Why does database owner NOT have permissions to query its own database?

EDIT:
I upgraded `bspu` to superuser for now, so I can continue work. Any further guidance appreciated.

Comment: What does the output of `\dt "users"` show?

Comment: @bma only my main acc is listed.

Comment: You ran the initial commands as what user? What do you get from `SELECT session_user, current_user` at the top of your script? And what is your Postgres version?

Comment: If these were the exact commands you've run, then you are still connected with your 'main acc'.  So it comes down what privileges _you_ have.  Otherwise, see Erwin's excellent answer.  (Let me admit that I feel it dumb that this error message does not tell which role does not have permission.  For example, when one runs a chain of functions with SECURITY DEFINER, it pretty fast gets confusing who is who.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) do *not* change permissions for *existing* objects. They are the default privileges for newly created objects and only for the particular role they belong to. If you do not specify the role when running `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, it defaults to the *current* role (when executing the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement.

Also, since you are using a [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column, which creates a [`SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html), you'll want to set default privileges for sequences as well.

Run this on the user you create objects with, ***before*** you run the `CREATE` command:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES [ FOR ROLE my_create_role] GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO bspu;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES [ FOR ROLE my_create_role] GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO bspu;
```

A word of caution for pgAdmin users. There is a bug in all versions of pgAdmin III and pgAdmin4 (including v5.3). The reverse engineered SQL script for the database or schema nodes displays `DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` ignoring  the owning user and is therefore incorrect in certain situations. I [reported the bug (repeatedly)](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAGHENJ78GVyYS-uhzB5d0Y_48so0GKNqEiCPTLTe56XHYb8NWA%40mail.gmail.com#30314113a417241969035f1bfdce1304), but the project encountered difficulties fixing it. pgAdmin III was discontinued in favor of pgAdmin4. The bug is still there in pgAdmin4.

For *existing* objects you may also be interested in this "batch" form of the [`GRANT` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO bspu;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO bspu;
```

More under this related question on SO:

- [Grant all on a specific schema in the db to a group role in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353730/939860)

Comment: The bug mentioned still persists in pgAdmin4, see https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4685, which has been flagged as a duplicate of https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4256

Comment: If GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES reports the error "permission denied for relation users"
Then use the psql command 
\dt 
To see the owner of each table. You may have an owner of a table who can not be assigned privleges.

Answer (score 2):

If the error

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation migrations
```

pops up when trying to do a GRANT ACTION,

```
example:GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name to ro_user;
```

ensure the GRANT is performed by the user that is the owner of the respective tables.
Owner of schemas might vary within a database. Even postgres user will not be allowed to provide this GRANT access.

Answer (score 2):

For PostgreSQL. On bash terminal, run this:

```bash
psql db_name -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to db_user;"
psql db_name -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to db_user;"
psql db_name -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public to db_user;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is working for me after some research. psql (9.6.12)

-- login to postgres database server as postgres user.
ssh <user>>@hostname.<domain>>.com
sudo su postgres
id
psql
postgres=# create user sentry_read with login password 'sentry_read';
postgres=# du+
postgres=# \l+
-- **very important: make sure we should connect required database before we grant to user.**
postgres=# \c sentry
postgres=# \dt
sentry=# \dp SENTRY_VERSION
sentry=# select * from "SENTRY_VERSION";
sentry=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO sentry_read;
postgres=# \q

[user@hostname ~]$ psql -U sentry_read -d sentry -h hostname.<domain>>.com -W
sentry=> select * from "SENTRY_VERSION";
```

Comment: This helped me out.
I was unable to GRANT on all tables in the schema as kept getting the same error. "permission denied for relation users"
Running \dt showed me that one of my tables was owned by an old read-only user. 
Dropping the table allowed me to use the techniques from the approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```sql
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS extensao.tipo_prestacao_servico
    OWNER to sigaa;
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS extensao.categoria_prestacao_servico
    OWNER to sigaa;
```